# Spring Data Rest problems with Project Lombok

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest, lombok

Is there any known problems in using Spring Data Rest with Lombok?

I have a Spring Boot project with Spring Data JPA, Spring Data REST, MySql connector and Project Lombok as dependencies.

If I define a simple entity (with name and description fields):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Devicetype")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class DeviceType {

    /** Unique Entity Id */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long uid;

    /** DeviceType name */
    private String name;

    /** DeviceType description */
    private String description;

}
```

Then building and running the service, I can invoke it with a curl command to create (POST) a new entity:

```
 curl -d "{ \"name\":\<TYPE NAME>\", \"description\":\"<TYPE DESC>\" }" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:8082/deviceTypes | jq
```

correctly returning the json resource:

```
{
  "name": "<TYPE NAME>",
  "description": "<TYPE DESC>",
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8082/deviceTypes/22"
    },
    "deviceType": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8082/deviceTypes/22"
    }
  }
}
```

If add the `@RestRepository` annotation to change the endpoint name:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Devicetype")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@RestResource(path = "types", rel = "types")
public class DeviceType {
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Then the POST results in not adding the two fields to the generated entity

```
curl -d "{ \"name\":\"<TYPE NAME>\", \"description\":\"<TYPE DESC>\" }" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:8082/deviceTypes | jq
     

    {
      "_links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "http://localhost:8082/types/22"
        },
        "types": {
          "href": "http://localhost:8082/types/22"
        }
      }
    }
```

This is a simple entity, but other that I need to add contains a lot of fields, so not using the `@Data` annotation would represent a big loss.

The following is my pom.xml file. In there any problem of incompatibility between lombok and spring data resta annotations?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0-M1</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    
    <groupId>eu.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp-service</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myapp-service</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <docker.image.prefix>myapp.eu</docker.image.prefix>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <imageName>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}:${project.version}</imageName>
                    <dockerDirectory>src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                            <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Maven Dependency Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    </project>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Java doc of RestResource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/core/annotation/RestResource.html)

> Annotate a Repository with this to influence how it is exported and what the value of the rel attribute will be in links.
> As of Spring Data REST 2.0, prefer using RepositoryRestResource to also be able to customize the relation type and description for the item resources exposed by the repository.

So, instead of adding `@RestResource(path = "types", rel = "types")` to the class `DeviceType`, add `@RepositoryRestResource(path = "types", collectionResourceRel = "types")` to the repository interface `DeviceTypeRepository`.

The `path` value defines the path segment under which this resource is to be exported. So the URI is changed from `http://localhost:8082/deviceTypes` to `http://localhost:8082/types`. Use the new URI in the `POST` request.

The `collectionResourceRel` value defines the relation value to use when generating links to the collection resource, that is, the name under `_links`. In your example,

```json
    {
      "_links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "http://localhost:8082/types/22"
        },
        "types": {  <-- this name !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
          "href": "http://localhost:8082/types/22"
        }
      }
    }
```

A sample project is uploaded to [Github](https://github.com/yejianfengblue/so65939000). The first commit is before add `@RepositoryRestResource` and the second commit is after add `@RepositoryRestResource`. The project contains test cases to verify the change of path and collection relation.

Comment: I tried to replace the annotations as you suggest, but unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem. thanks anyway.

Comment: @chrx I add a sample project and test case to verify the change. There might be configuration class or file which is not posted in the question. It helps a lot if you also upload a sample to demonstrate your problem.